# Graph api v2 best practice and facebook unity sdk on mobile

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'd like to know how to correctly follow the best practice for api v2. I'm currently unable to re-ask a declined permission on mobile (6.1 release note fix this on canvas, still not working on mobile with sdk 6.2b), there's no FBSession or FBAccessTokenData equivalent (present in ios or android sdk), so we have to call FB.Api to get permissions, cannot get declined permission. Json returned by FB.api differ from graph tools
f.e. :
graph tool for /me/permissions => { "data": [{"permission": "permissionName", "status": "granted"}, ...] }
unity sdk => { "data": [{"permissionName": 1}, ...] }

Will the facebook sdk evolve to offer the same features as native plug in or should I use another sdk ?

Comment: Precision : I cannot re-ask if user delete permission from facebook parameters. I can re-ask if user respond later or cancel at fb permission pop-up

Comment: I found a solution to get correct json format, I force /v2.2. I do not understand why I have to do it while the documentation says "Now defaults to calling Graph API v2.2"